# (IOS) TabBarController, only 3 tabs and tab (More) fix

Tags: ios, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I can create 4 fixed tabs and the fourth is always (more)?

I want the limit to tab(more) appears to be 4 and not 6,
if I have 3 views tab(more) shouldn't be appear, but if I have 4 views the first three tabs should be appear, and the fourth should be appear into the array(more).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[customizableViewControllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/customizableViewControllers) is the property to look for. Add your ViewControllers in the array you want to customize or want to display in More Tab of the `UITabBarController` and assign to `customizableViewControllers` array.